How can I upload image to AWS S3 bucket using pre-signed URL?
I would like to upload my image to AWS S3 using a pre-signed url created from backend. So, the process is - after submitting a form from Angular application, I'll send an API request to Node.js backend for creating a pre-signed url and response back to Angular application. Using the pre-signed url Angular application will send a http request to the pre-signed url along with an image file.
So, at first I created a S3 bucket by adding following CORS policy.
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:4200"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]

Also, I created a IAM policy -
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PolicyName",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<timezone>-<bucket_name >",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<timezone>-<bucket_name >/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Here is the Node.js code that create and send pre-signed upload url -
exports.getS3SignedUrl = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const s3 = new S3({
            apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
            accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
            signatureVersion: 'v4',
            region: process.env.AWS_REGION
        });

        const ext = req.query.fileType ? (req.query.fileType).split('/')[1] : null;

        if (ext) {
            const Key = `${randomUUID()}.${ext}`;

            const s3Params = {
                Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
                Key,
                Expires: 60 * 60,
                ContentType: `image/${ext}`
            }
            const uploadUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params);
            
            return res.status(200).json({
                uploadUrl,
                Key
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'File not found'
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ "error": error });
    }
}

Node.js code can create a pre-signed url and send it to Angular frontend. But the issue I am facing with uploading the file to AWS S3. When I execute a http request to the pre-signed url, it returns back a 400 bad request.
Here is the frontend code -
  .......
  const s3BucketUploadInformation = await 
     this.getS3SignedUrl(file);
  await this.saveFileToS3Bucket(s3BucketUploadInformation.uploadUrl, 
     file);
  .......

  // We would not upload files to AWS S3 from the backend, instead of we would ask 
  // backend to create a AWS signed URL, later from the front end upload the file to 
  // S3 bucket.
  public async saveFileToS3Bucket(uploadUrl: string, file: File) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': file.type });
    const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', uploadUrl, file, { headers: headers, reportProgress: true })
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.request(req)
        .toPromise()
        .then(
          res => { // Success
            resolve(res);
          },
          msg => { // Error
            reject(msg);
          }
        );
    });
    return promise;
  }

  // Get AWS S3 signed url from backend.
  public getS3SignedUrl(file: File) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileType: string = encodeURIComponent(file.type);
      let apiURL = `${environment.API_ADMIN_URL}content/get-s3-signed-url?fileType=${fileType}`;
      // Send API request to get AWS S3 signed URL, and an unique key from backend.
      this.http.get(apiURL)
        .toPromise()
        .then(
          res => { // Success
            resolve(res);
          },
          msg => { // Error
            reject(msg);
          }
        );
    });
    return promise;
  }

Here is the actual error I get from the http request that was sent to AWS S3 as a pre-signed upload url -

InvalidArgumentOnly one auth mechanism
allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query
string parameter or the Authorization header should be
specifiedAuthorizationBearer
--bearer----requestId----hostId--

